# Automatically run my Chrome extension upon loading a specific website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I build up a chrome extension, and I want it to automatically work when I am watching some specific websites, say "Youtube", how can I make it? Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "bla bla",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "gjx.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
  "permissions": [
  "http://localhost/*",
   "tabs",
   "cookies",
   "storage"
   ],
  "background":["crawler.js"],
  "content_scripts":[{
  "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
  "js": ["crawler.js"]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, here `script.js` will automatically execute on the Youtube page that you are on.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

I recommend reading about matches and content scripts [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: @SiruiLi Can you add your `manifest.json` and your content script to the question?

Comment: Here it is. @PredatorIWD

Comment: @SiruiLi You can also show your `crawler.js` but this should already work. Do you get any errors?

Comment: my extension should pop up a small window and show some results, but it does not. If I click it, it works.

Comment: my extension should pop up a small window and show some results, but it does not. If I click it, it works. @PredatorIWD

Comment: @SiruiLi I cant help without knowing how your other scripts work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the desired URL pattern to `permissions` in `manifest.json`.
You have:

```
"permissions": [
   "http://localhost/*",
   "tabs",
   "cookies",
   "storage"
   ]
```

You have to add your desired URL pattern, like:

```
"permissions": [
   "http://localhost/*",
   "tabs",
   "cookies",
   "storage",
   "*://*.youtube.com/*
   ]
```